# wxScrolledWindow scrollbar not working

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have the following child-parent relasions in my application:

[image]

The problem is that there is no visible ( or working ) scrollbar in wxScrolledWindow.

Code:

```
wxCollapsiblePane* collpane = new wxCollapsiblePane(this, ID_COLLPANE, "Tiles\t\t\t\t", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxCP_NO_TLW_RESIZE);
wxSizer* sz = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
sz->Add(collpane,0,wxALIGN_RIGHT,10);
SetSizer(sz);
wxWindow* cPane = collpane->GetPane();
wxSizer* panesz = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
wxBitmap pic("test.bmp",wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP);
wxScrolledWindow* scr = new wxScrolledWindow(cPane,ID_PANEL,wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(150,300));
scr->SetScrollbars(2,2,10,10);
wxClientDC dc(this);
scr->DoPrepareDC(dc);
panesz->Add( new wxBitmapButton(scr,-1,pic, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50,50) ), 1,  wxALIGN_CENTER, 0 );
/* more button adding here */
cPane->SetSizer(panesz);
panesz->SetSizeHints(cPane);
```

How can I get the scrollbar to show and scroll the buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have scrollbars you need to indicate to `wxScrolledWindow` its full logical (as opposed to possibly smaller physical) size using `SetVirtualSize()` method. This can be done either just by calling it directly or by associating a sizer with the scrolled window, adding elements to this sizer and calling `FitInside()`.

Answer (score 4):

In the default state, for the scroll bars to appear the virtual size of the window has to be larger than the actual size of the window.

```
scr->SetVirtualSize(wxSize(2000,2000));
```

However, in version 3.1 this is not enough to get the scroll bars to appear. One also has to set the scroll rate. (This feels like a bug to me as it seems there ought to be a default setting that works.)

```
scr->SetScrollRate(1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Very important addition to the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, this really saved a great deal of time. It so happens that when setting the virtual size it works when virtual size is greater or equal but not when virtual size is smaller than the previous virtual size (in case of zooming in and out). However, adding the `SetScrollRate` made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the

```
wxWindow* cPane = collpane->GetPane();
wxSizer* panesz = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
wxBitmap pic("test.bmp",wxBITMAP_TYPE_B ...
```

You should put a jpg. After modifying this, it will work for sure ;) Trust me.

Comment: I admit I don't get the joke here, but it must be one because this can't possibly change anything, of course...